# JAX-WS - How to avoid annotations

Tags: jax-ws

WSGEN -- is it mandatory that SEI class should be annotated with @Webservice?
Is there any way to avoid annotating the java class

Comment: What is the reason that you want to avoid the @WebService annotation?

Comment: I dont want to disturb the existing services which i want to expose it as a webservice.

Comment: I do not see how existing services can be disturbed by adding @WebService annotation. If your existing service uses the same class as POJO and EJB, it will still work. If there is a special use case that we do not know, please explain.

Comment: I have a Service without @WebService annotation.... now I need to support this to expose it as a webservice without touching the existing class.

Comment: In that case, you can either extend the existing class or create a proxy class passing all the calls to the existing class. You then annotate the methods in the new class with @WebService.

Comment: Thanks Surge. I have a plan to create this using any of the provided IDE's provided Delegate classes. Could you suggest me if i get any sample class like that.

Answer (score 0):

If you choose bottom-up approach, apparently not. SEI is a mandatory parameter of `wsgen` tool, and you have to specify that particular Java class **is** SEI. An excerpt regarding SEI from [Java EE 6 tutorial](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E19798-01/821-1841/bnbos/index.html):

- The class must be annotated with either the `javax.jws.WebService` or
  the `javax.jws.WebServiceProvider` annotation.

See also:

- [Exposing methods in SEI-based JAX-WS Web services](http://pic.dhe.ibm.com/infocenter/wasinfo/v7r0/topic/com.ibm.websphere.express.iseries.doc/info/iseriesexp/ae/twbs_devjaxws_exposewebmethod.html)
- [wsgen](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/technotes/tools/share/wsgen.html)